# Curves simplify to lines?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I have what is supposed to be a curve:

$$25x^2 - 4y^2 = 100$$

When simplify this to be:

$$y = 2.5x - 5$$

it is a line.

But isn't it supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you've gone from

$$25x^2-4y^2 = 100$$

to

$$5x-2y=10\;?$$

This is not a valid operation; the square root (or any other power) of a sum is not the sum of the square roots (or powers) of the individual terms.

Comment: ouch, now I feel ashamed. Thank you! :)

Comment: No need to. Live and learn -- better to have tried and failed than never to have tried at all :-)